# generate sets of normal distribution values within for loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to capture 500 samples of a linear model, where each sample contains 20 error terms that are randomly-generated values of a normal distribution.

Because I'm interested in results per sample, I don't want to just generate a vector of 500 * 20 = 10000 values of a normal distribution.

My code is:

```
for (i in 1:500) {
    e <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 4)
}
```

The problem is that this code generates 20 values, once. So each of the 500 samples have the same 20 error terms. How can I generate 20 new values for each iteration of the 500-iteration for-loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I believe it.  Are you using `set.seed()`?  How about `matrix(rnorm(20*500,0,4),ncol=20)` ?

Comment: Does running `for (i in 1:2) {print(rnorm(n=20, mean=0, sd=4))}` really print the same vector twice for you? It certainly doesn't for me.

Comment: you're assigning the rnorm values to e each time, How about e[i] <-rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 4)? and declare e <-as.list() before the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confused about what your loop is actually doing. It reassigns a newly allocated random vector to your variable `e` 500 consecutive times. This means that every iteration `e` is overwritten with a new random vector. Hence, after the loop is finished you end up with one random vector that is now assigned to `e`. You are basically just defining `e` in a very inefficient way :)

I assume, what you want to do is most likely something like this:

```
nrSamples = 500
e <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)
for (i in 1:nrSamples) {
  e[[i]] <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 4)
}
```

You first define `e` as a list that can contain up to 500 vectors. In your loop a random vector is first created and then assigned to its respective position in the list. This is done 500 times for each unique listindex.

You can now acces your random vectors as follows:

```
> vector_1 <- e[[1]]
> vector_7 <- e[[7]]
> vector_1
 [1]  3.8713046  3.4672930  4.2840856  4.0388847 -3.0535864 -4.1402421 -2.7912700 -1.2332116  3.2628433  3.5377208
[11] -1.0929493  0.6466984 -5.5490625 -7.3033997  1.0898727  0.2001674  2.2646435  0.1623863  2.2611607 -1.1867225
> vector_7
 [1]  0.8199701 -3.1517209 -1.1319827  6.3150359 -3.7589505  1.4065123 -0.5410125 -3.0186291  6.6353592 -0.5002009
[11] -3.7416365  5.5324850 -2.2105955 -1.0931199 -2.0189795 -5.4934535  2.4210809  1.0956980 -7.6284702 -1.3574990
```

As you can see, the random vectors are not identical. They are randomly and independently generated from eachother. In order to access the individual elements of your random vectors you can do this:

```
> vector_7[[3]]
[1] -1.131983
> # OR
> e[[7]][[3]]
[1] -1.131983
```

Answer (score 3):

`rnorm()` is a vectorized function.

Therefore `matrix(rnorm(500 * 20, 0, 4), nrow = 500))` or similar should work.

```
set.seed(1237)
head(matrix(rnorm(500 * 20, 0, 4), nrow = 500), 2)

[,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]      [,11]
[1,] -1.779413  2.0934980 -0.1130465 0.7155059 -4.357417 -0.1000385 -5.4510753 -2.135156 0.2134115 -6.747588  2.3818280
[2,] -7.892865 -0.6712141 -4.0481822 5.2750330 -3.053245  0.7502157  0.6026951  4.951890 1.8733383  1.860631 -0.7452204
[,12]     [,13]    [,14]     [,15]      [,16]     [,17]     [,18]     [,19]      [,20]
[1,]  4.0730359 -3.246457 5.781667 2.4091225 -8.4262348 7.1438989  3.289772 -4.136308 -0.7102701
[2,] -0.5159794  4.144834 5.662559 0.9685914  0.9033701 0.3952698 10.734498 -2.213788 -2.3064852
```

Answer (score 2):

Running your code, the end of the loop will return one set of 20 numbers:

```
for (i in 1:500) {
    e <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 4)
}

> e
[1]  7.48112400 -3.76594695 -1.55396151 -0.88205322  1.00736518  1.61904598 -4.69739057 -0.65291410
[9] -1.11921165  1.35657106 -8.33957962 -1.80607461 -0.05524872 -1.79938725 -0.98579993  6.32969133
[17]  2.83715482 -1.56407249 -6.56056515  0.65830884
```

You'll need to create a list and store each iteration of e inside it, as @infominer suggests:

```
e <- list()

for (i in 1:500) {
    e[i] <- list(rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 4))
}
```